# C# type requiring subclass of specific class as well as interfaces

Tags: c#, interface, subclass

I am working on a utility that will have an interface for "Filters" with a number of implementations of that interface. Part of the interface will return an object of type Control that will be used in a UI for manipulating the filters.

I would like to be able to require that the returned control also implement another interface so that I can do things like request that the controls write back to the object that created them.

right now my code looks like:

```
public interface IFilter
{
    Control Control();
}
```

I would like someting like:

```
public interface IFilterControl
{
    ...
}

public class FilterControl : Control, IFilterControl{}

public interface IFilter
{
    ...
    FilterControl Control();
}
```

The above does not work because FilterControl does not actually implement IFilterControl.

If the above is not clear enough try to visualize how the imaginary keyword "implmenting" would work below

```
public interface IFilterControl
{
    IFilter Filter{get;}
}

public interface IFilter
{
    Control implmenting IFilterControl Control();
}

public interface FilterImpl : IFilter
{
    Control implmenting IFilterControl Control(){
        return new FilterControlImpl(this);
    }
}

public partial class FilterImplControl : UserControl, IFilterControl
{
    FilterImpl filter;
    public FilterImplControl(FilterImpl filter)
    {
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    public IFilter Filter{get{return filter;}}
}


FilterImpl a_filter = GetAFilter();
Control implmenting IFilterControl ctl = a_filter;
panel.Controls.Add(ctl);
FilterImpl the_filter_indirectly = ctl.Filter;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might want to look at using generics. They'll let you place constraints on the type.

```
public interface IFilter<T> where T : Control
{
    T Control { get; set; }
    T ControlMethod();
}
```

The where clause is a generic restraint and will require that T is always of type Control. It works for interfaces as well. That way, you know those methods or properties are always a derivative of Control and those expectations will show up in intellisense.

EDIT
Oh, just occurred to me that you can apply the generic solely at the method if you'd prefer.

```
interface IFilter
{
    T Control<T>() where T : Control;
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea, @JacobProffit. In fact, you can constrain T on both the class and the interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx#csharp_generics_topic4).

Comment: Right. Generics with constraints are awesome. :)

Comment: It is not clear to me how a class withg a collection of IFilter instances could call Control() without knowing T in this case. Can you expand the example?

Comment: In the second case, it's relatively easy, it calls it with an explicit reference to Control. In other words, it calls it with filtervar.Control<Control>().

Comment: In the first case, it has to define the type T in the list declaration, so that shouldn't be an issue, either.